# Can't send email with laravel 5.1 + gmail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, laravel-5.1

I'm having troubles sending e-mails via a Laravel 5.1 application using gmail.

Here is my config file :

```
 <?php
    return [
            'driver' => 'sendmail',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 578,
            'from' => array('address' => 'adresse@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Something'),
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'someaddress@gmail.com',
            'password' => '****',
            'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
            'pretend' => false,

    ];
```

Allowing less secure apps to access your account is turned on.

What config shall I use ?

Answer (score 2):

You must to allow less secure apps [here](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps) and Enable Unlock Captcha [here](https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha)

Also, Set `.env` as follows

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=something@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And Set `config/mail.php` as follows

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => 'something@gmail.com',
    'name'    => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Admin'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','something@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','*********'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Hope it's Help!